# How Recover state from previous Spinner and Radiobuttons in a new Activity?

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner, state

My problem is:

I instantiate objects such as graphics android Spinner and radiogroup (containing 2 radiobutton) in my first activity.

Return values ​​of these objects are returned to me in my SQLite database.

I wonder how the state recover from these objects to repost in another view.

thank you

Comment: You need to reword your question. It isn't clear what the problem is or what you are asking.

Comment: Hi David, i've a User Profil screen at the first launching of my app.Then you can choose different values from 2 spinners and a value from radiobuttons. Then you click on "Start Application Now" button, application runs and i want to re display these info with good checked values (setted before).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the problem :-( What have you tried? What doesn' work? If you are just starting another activity when the user clicks "start application now", then when that activity ends it should resume your activity and it should show the same values as it did before.

Comment: When i finished User Profil activity (with 3 values selected) i put a finish() statement on it and we start the main activity. I don't want to display the same first User Profil activity on this main activity but just the 2 spinners and the radio button with values setted before. When i try to recreate spinners on my activity wich a re linked with old spinners and radiobutton id (created before on my layout), it doesn't display buttons with values setted before (it displays spinners and radiobutton with nothing check and set).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the information about which spinner items were selected to the main activity. You can do that by using **extras** in the `Intent` you use to start the activity, or you could store this information in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I don't really know how to use Extras with Intent :S (i don't want to use Preferences because i store the values into my Local Data Base). I will work on Extras because i'm sure its the only way to fix that. :)

Comment: Well, if you already store the values in your local database, why don't you just retrieve them from the database in the main activity? Otherwise, extras are easy. It is just a set of name/value pairs that you attach to the Intent.